# Easy secure JSON-RPC in python

Tags: python, json, pyjamas

What's the simplest way to set up a JSON-RPC server in python and make it secure?  I'm very interested Pyjamas for python/javascript - but the documentation doesn't explain how to implement security with the JSON-RPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've played with pyjamas a little and am currently implementing json-rpc with django.

Have you considered using ssl to secure the site. Short of implementing your own (basic) encryption routine, its probably the best way forward.

Comment: Do you mean to distribute SSL client certs to all the clients?